# How to stop the while loop after four hours in shell script, if the file not found?

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I am working on the ksh script where I am getting the file from the sftp server & copying to local & checking if the file is available there or not. I am running this on loop if the file is available then it will immediately come out from the loop & continue with the rest of the script. If file not available then its sleeping for 5 minutes & then again its searching for the file in sftp server.

I need to add the logic in the below code to abort the loop & fail the script after 4 hours & send an email saying file not found after four hours of searching. I am not getting how to proceed with this code. It's confusing.

```
PROCESS=0
    while [[ ${PROCESS} -ne 1 ]]; do
    echo "Connecting to sftp" >> $log
    sftp uname$host_name <<EOF
        cd folder
        get filename
        bye
EOF

    CHECK=`find "${source}" -maxdepth 1 -name "file_name" -mtime -2 | egrep '.*' | wc -l`
    echo -e "Number of files found ${CHECK}" >> $log
        if [[ ${CHECK} -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo -e "ERROR :: file not found.Will sleep for 5 minutes. ---`date` \n" >> $log
            SendMail --This is a function
            sleep 300
        elif [[ ${CHECK} -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo -e "file found in ${source}" >> $log
            PROCESS=1
        fi
    done
```

Comment: four hours is 4x3600 = 14400 seconds, or 4x12 = 48 five minute periods. Add a counter to see how many times the loop has repeated? Or run `date +%s` at the start and on each iteration to check if the wall clock time has advanced enough? Or check the same using `$SECONDS` in Bash.

Comment: @ilkkachu $SECONDS not working since its ksh not bash. Could you please help me in using this logic in above mentioned code. I am trying since long but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for a timer isn't difficult. This version uses the built-in `$SECONDS` variable that `ksh` (and `bash`) offers, which automatically increments every second.

```
hours=4
end_time=$(( (hours*60*60) + SECONDS ))

while [ "$SECONDS" -le "$end_time" ]
do
    # stuff
    sleep 5
done
```

To incorporate this into your existing loop you just need to extend the `while` condition to exit either if the timer expires or you get your file:

```
while [ "$PROCESS" -ne 1 ]
do
    # Check for timeout
    if [ "$SECONDS" -gt "$end_time" ]
    then
        # Report an error
        echo "ERROR: File still not found after ${hours:-some} hours" >&2

        # Send an email using whatever tools you have
        # ...

        # Exit
        exit 1
    fi

    # Look for the file
    # ...
    sleep 5
done
```

Notice that curly brackets around simple variables mean very little in shell scripting, but double-quotes are very important. Use `"$PROCESS"` instead of `${PROCESS}`, for example. And throughout your code.